# Limit Number of stack trace lines in JSONLayout

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to print my application logs using log4j2-`<JsonLayout/>`. The problem I am facing is - for some of the logs, the stackTrace becomes too huge as `<JsonLayout/>` prints **extendedStackTrace** for every nested exception.

The goal is to have extendedStackTrace, or the stackTrace in log message but upto a certain limit.

is there a way to limit number of lines in **extendedStackTrace**?